# How can I populate Extended Methods with EF5 and return IQueryable (without looping)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, breeze, iqueryable

I'm new to Entity Framework. This is my first project using it.

I've created a new class that extends my "merchant" entity with new properties, which are mostly calculated totals. I could not figure out the best way to populate those new properties with data. I am using breeze.js to query an iQueryable endpoint so I need to keep this functionality intact.

I found the following solution, but it is very slow because I have to loop through every record. Despite the fact I have implemented paging in breeze the loop still hits every single record, though it only returns one page. I guess that is just how entity framework works. My question is how do I populate extended properties without looping?

Here is my code that works, but it is slow. Can I eliminate this loop and fill that extended property with a value?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Merchant> MerchantList()
    {
        IQueryable<Merchant> items = _repo.Context.Merchants;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {

            // Total Stores
            item.TotalStores = myMethod(item.MerchantUID);

        }

        return items;

    }
```

Comment: You are looking for the `Include` method.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply. I am researching this Include method and it seems it is used to "eager load" related entities usually resulting in a join.  I'm not really catching on to how this would help me load the data into extended properties and avoid the loop.  If you have time can you please elaborate more?

Comment: what is "myMethod" doing?  Based on what you are passing into it, is it possible to use other properties in the Merchant class to populate TotalStores?

Comment: "myMethod" is a function that queries the "Stores" table to get a Count of the total stores.  There are several other properties I need to include though that also query the db with more complex queries. For example, some additional extended properties for merchant are "life time value" and "days left in trial".  Ideally I want to get rid of this loop, but the loop could be OK if it only did the current page... not the entire table.

Comment: You need to show `myMethod` to get a proper answer to this. Without seeing the implementation it's impossible to guess what you are doing in there and how it can be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code above has been reduced from the original.  I am trying to populate several properties in this loop that cannot be combined. This is actually the problem in of itself.  So viewing all of the code for these different methods will not provide any insight.  What I am asking if there is a way to load an extended property automatically without looping through the entire repo? (e.g. a "new" method in EF?) Or is there a way to only loop the items on the current page instead of the entire repo?  I could call these all individually from the client, but that seems crazier.

Comment: So you should eager load all data involved in the combined properties. You really should show an example of what happens in `myMethod`. So far this is a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are looping through the whole tables worth of data on the off chance someone gets *some* of the rows. I'm not familiar with `Breeze` but I have worked with `OData` before so hopefully this solution will work for you.

I suggest that you stop exposing `IQueryable<>` and manage the query internally. This will enable you to add the additional information to only those records that you are returning to the client. Here's some rough code to point you in the right direction:

```
[HttpGet]
public PageResult<Merchant> MerchantList(
    ODataQueryOptions<Merchant> queryOptions)
{
    var t = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxTop = 25 };
    var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 25 };
    queryOptions.Validate(t);
    IEnumerable<Merchant> results =
        (IEnumerable<Merchant>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(_repo.Context.Merchants, s);

    int skip = queryOptions.Skip == null ? 0 : queryOptions.Skip.Value;
    int take = queryOptions.Top == null ? 25 : queryOptions.Top.Value;
    long? count = Request.GetInlineCount();

    List<Merchant> pageOfResults = results.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

    PageResult<Merchant> page =
        new PageResult<Merchant>(
            pageOfResults, 
            Request.GetNextPageLink(), 
            Request.GetInlineCount());

    foreach (var item in page)
    {

        // Total Stores
        item.TotalStores = myMethod(item.MerchantUID);

    }

    return page;
}
```

and the `using`s

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check with the Breeze docs and find out if this will be compatible.  If so, then it seems like a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the direction. The suggestion that came the closest was the one about using oData.  I researched eager loading, but that seems to apply to joining entities and these properties cannot be combined. I will probably do more research with "include" to determine if it can be used to load a single property, but I couldn't find any documentation on it used that way. Another thing that came close was projection, but EF doesn't allow projecting to the same type.  I could have projected to a partial class, but then I would loose the MetaData that breeze needs. If not for breeze that would have been a really nice solution.  In the end, while Breeze does support oData it has too many limitations (such as cannot be cached), so I wanted to stay with IQueryable.

This is what I came up with.  It now only loops through the current page, but it still gets a count on the main query so Breeze can do paging on the client.  This is all possible because Breeze allows me to send get parameters so I can offload the paging to the server.  This took tons of research and it still isn't perfect, but it does load very fast so I have to move on for now.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [BreezeQueryable]
    public QueryResult MerchantList(int take, int skip)
    {

        IQueryable<Merchant> main = _repo.Context.Merchants.OrderBy(m => m.MerchantUID);

        IQueryable<Merchant> items = main.Skip(skip).Take(take);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {

            // Total LifetimeVal
            item.LifetimeVal= TotalLifetimeVal(item.MerchantUID);

            // Total Stores
            item.TotalStores = TotalStores(item.MerchantUID);

        }


        // return items;
        return new QueryResult
        {
            InlineCount = main.Count(),
            Results = items.ToList()
        };

    }
```

Comment: This still does not mean much to others when it's not clear what the methods within the loop do. It looks like you could exploit eager loading when you pass `item` in stead of `item.MerchantUID`, but yeah, who knows?

Comment: This will mean something to people using Breeze JS.  It made it possible to assign extended properties without looping through the entire table. I also addressed not loosing Meta Data, which is incredibly important to Breeze. Could it be better?  Maybe, but it did what I wanted.  Also, no one is showing me an example of eager loading an arbitrary property.  I understand you eager load other entities (similar to a join).  Can you show me how to eager load an arbitrary method, for instance a value calculated by an enormous stored procedure?